# React Login Auth fails

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app that authenticates users by comparing data received from user with a API call. But when I submit the data it says

```
POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found)
```

Wondering where am I going wrong here

Given below is the auth code that checks the API

```
const authenticateUser = async (email, password) => {
  const secret = "abc";
  const base_url = "https://api.site.com";
  const app_id = "xyz";
  const timestamp = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-:]/g, "").slice(0, 14);
  const base_string = `${app_id}--${timestamp}`;
  const secret = secret;
  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    username: email,
    password: password,
  });
  const signature = await generateSignature(base_string, secret);
  const user_service_url = `${base_url}/api/v1/users/login? 
   app_id=${app_id}&timestamp=${timestamp}&signature=${signature}`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(user_service_url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: payload,
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();
      const { token, user } = data;

      // The user is authenticated, return the user details and token
      return {
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
       email: user.email,
        token: token,
      };
    } else {
      // Authentication failed, return null or throw an error based on your preference
      return null;
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occurred during the API call
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    throw new Error("Internal server error");
  }
};
```

**POST Call for login**

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const userData = await authenticateUser(email, password);

    if (userData) {
      // Authentication successful, generate token and send response
      const token = generateToken(); // Replace with your token generation logic

      res.json({
        success: true,
        message: "Login successful",
        ...userData,
        token: token,
      });
    } else {
      // Authentication failed, send error response
      res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Invalid email or password",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occurred during authentication or token generation
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Internal server error",
    });
  }
});
```

Given below is the code for Auth.js file

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

const Auth = () => {
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies();
  const authToken = cookies.AuthToken;
  const userEmail = cookies.Email;
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState();

  console.log(email, password, confirmPassword);

  const viewLogin = (status) => {
    setError(null);
    setIsLogin(status);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e, endpoint) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!isLogin && password !== confirmPassword) {
      setError("Make sure password match");
      return;
    }

    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${endpoint}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-type": "applicaton/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.detail) {
      setError(data.detail);
    } else {
      setCookie("Email", data.email);
      setCookie("AuthToken", data.token);

      window.location.reload();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth-container">
      <div className="auth-container-box">
        <form>
          <h2>{isLogin ? "Please log in" : "Please sign up"}</h2>
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="email"
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="password"
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />

          {!isLogin && (
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="confirm pass"
              onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          )}
          <input
            type="submit"
            className="create"
            onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e, isLogin ? "login" : "signup")}
          />
          {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        </form>

        <div className="auth-options">
          <button
            onClick={() => viewLogin(false)}>
            Sign up
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => viewLogin(true)}>
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```